# Odd number of posts aren't showing up

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, blogs

Using bootstrap in wordpress, I'm trying to get my blog page to have the 1st latest post as a col-sm-12 (which is working) and then have the remaining posts fall into 2 columns where all the even # posts show up in the left column and the odd # posts show up in the right column. My left column loop is working but my right column isn't pulling the odd posts starting at the 3rd post ... please help! http://dev.starship.capital/blog/

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 style="color: white; text-align: center;">Latest Posts</h2>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : $i++; if(($i % 2) == 0) : $wp_query->next_post(); else : the_post(); ?>
    <?php endif; endwhile; else: ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 entry blog-menu">
            <article class="entry">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="blog-overlay"></div>
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('excerpt-thumb'); ?>
                </a>
                <div class="entry-content clear">
                    <div style="padding: 1% 15%;">
                        <?php the_category(); ?>
                        <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                        <p>Posted on: <?php the_time(get_option('date_format') ); ?> By <?php the_author(); ?> | <?php $totalcomments = get_comments_number(); echo $totalcomments; ?> Comments</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
            <?php endif; ?>
      </div>    

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : $i++; if(($i % 2) !== 0) : $wp_query->next_post(); else : the_post(); ?>
    <?php endif; endwhile; else: ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 entry blog-menu">
            <article class="entry">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="blog-overlay"></div>
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('excerpt-thumb'); ?>
                </a>
                <div class="entry-content clear">
                    <div style="padding: 1% 15%;">
                        <?php the_category(); ?>
                        <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                        <p>Posted on: <?php the_time(get_option('date_format') ); ?> By <?php the_author(); ?> | <?php $totalcomments = get_comments_number(); echo $totalcomments; ?> Comments</p> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
            <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endwhile;  ?>

      </div>
</div>
```